# How to make httpresponsemessage return object content value instead of object content structure

Tags: c#, rest, postman, httpresponsemessage

I am trying to build a web api that returns true but when i send my response through a HttpResponseMessage, Postman reads it as the structure of the HttpResponseMessage. Instead of sending the result in a string with the word true it returns the entire structure of the HttpResponseMessage. I have used the exact same method with other APIs that I have created So I don´t know why it is suddenly returning the wrong answer in postman.

I´ve tried switching methods to the Request method, I´ve also tried returning Mediatypeformater but that haven´t helped. Anyone have any ideas?

The code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Exportreport(string imei) //tristis est, valet doctrina
    {
        try
        {
           //bunches of code

            return new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)200)
            {
                 Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(bool), true, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
            };
        }
```

Response in postman:

[image]

Comment: Is there an issue with Postman only?

Comment: No, When I try posting to it from a c# application using restsharp I get the same problem.